# get all the rows descending by age and also only the ones with income=2?

Tags: r, statistics

lets say i have the following data:

[image]

how can i get all the rows descending by age and also only the ones with income=2?
Is it possible to do this without using additional libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```r
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(
  age = sample(0:100, 20, replace = TRUE),
  income = sample(1:3, 20, replace = TRUE)
)

df <- df[df$income == 2,]
df <- df[order(df$age),]

df
#>    age income
#> 18   8      2
#> 1   30      2
#> 7   49      2
#> 3   50      2
#> 5   66      2
#> 13  90      2
```

Comment: Is there an option to sort by INCOME=2 to be the first and then INCOME=3? And so on..

Comment: Try with`df[order(df$income, df$age),]` which orders first by income and by age in each income group.

Comment: but it will give me income=1 first

Comment: You want 2, 3, 1? Then one option would be to convert to a factor with the levels set in the appropriate order, i.e. `df[order(factor(df$income, levels = c(2, 3, 1)), df$age),]`